# timestamp required in tshark interval based output

Tags: tcp, tshark

I am using the below command to find **TCP retransmission** using tshark. I would like to have a timestamp in the **interval** column

```
tshark -i em3 -q -z io,stat,2,"COUNT(tcp.analysis.retransmission) tcp.analysis.retransmission"
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on 'em3'
^C429556 packets captured

=========================================================================
| IO Statistics                                                         |
|                                                                       |
| Interval size: 2 secs                                                 |
| Col 1: Frames and bytes                                               |
|     2: COUNT(tcp.analysis.retransmission) tcp.analysis.retransmission |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|          |1                   |2      |                               |
| Interval | Frames |   Bytes   | COUNT |                               |
|---------------------------------------|                               |
|  0 <>  2 |     13 |       810 |     0 |                               |
|  2 <>  4 |     17 |      1062 |     0 |                               |
|  4 <>  6 |  23889 |  67716172 |     5 |                               |
|  6 <>  8 |  85710 | 240490860 |    11 |                               |
|  8 <> 10 |  85810 | 240475662 |     9 |                               |
| 10 <> 12 |  86033 | 240492476 |    11 |                               |
| 12 <> 14 |  86172 | 240501536 |    10 |                               |
| 14 <> 16 |  61895 | 173008883 |     5 |                               |
| 16 <> 18 |     14 |       882 |     0 |                               |
| 18 <> 18 |      3 |       180 |     0 |                               |
=========================================================================
```

Comment: The wireshark IO Graph is super useful to visualize this sort of thing, and the timestamp is on the x axis.  Indeed, one of the first things I'll usually do when analyzing a capture is to bring up the IO graph of total traffic and tcp.analysis.flags to get a sense of what might be going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `-t` switch to display Time or Date and Time etc. From tshark [man](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html):

> -t a|ad|adoy|d|dd|e|r|u|ud|udoy
> Set the format of the packet timestamp printed in summary lines. The format can be one of:
>
> a absolute: The absolute time, as local time in your time zone, is the actual time the packet was captured, with no date displayed
>
> ad absolute with date: The absolute date, displayed as YYYY-MM-DD, and time, as local time in your time zone, is the actual time and date the packet was captured
>
> ...